# Passwords in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, passwords, dockerfile

How to avoid redundancy in Dockerfile for the value P@55w0rd?

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest as sqlbase 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app 
COPY ./sql-scripts /usr/src/app 
ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=P@55w0rd 
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y 
RUN /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & sleep 10 \
    && /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'P@55w0rd' -i ./init.sql \
    && pkill sqlservr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I would not put any password directly at the Dockerfile, for two reasons:

- Get your Dockerfile obsolete, forcing you to build a new image every time your password changes.
- Passwords or any other sensitive information should be handled in a safer way (it will depend on your use case).

In this particular case (which seems a non production case). Using ENV and ARG together would be the best approach:

```
ARG MSQL_SERVER_VERSION=2017-latest
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:$MSQL_SERVER_VERSION as sqlbase

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./sql-scripts /usr/src/app

ARG MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=P@55w0rd
ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD $MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
RUN /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & sleep 10 \
    && /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P $MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD -i ./init.sql \
    && pkill sqlservr
```

Having `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` as an `ARG` and assigning its value to the `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` environment variable makes your Dockerfile more flexible. This also let you use it at the `RUN` command to avoid redundancy.

You can learn more about how `ENV`, `ARG` (and its scope) work in [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `ENV` or `ARG` inside the Dockerfile:

For ex you can use ARG as shown below in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM busybox    
ARG user
USER $user
```

when you use `ARG` you have to pass the value when you build the docker image as :

```
docker build --build-arg user=what_user
```

You can also use ENV as shown below in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV CONT_IMG_VER hello
RUN echo $CONT_IMG_VER
```

You can refer to [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#impact-on-build-caching) for more info.